# Set default value for any item not listed in the array?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to apply by default a `boo` class to each `input type="submit"` whenever its attributed form action does not contain the string `special`.

Right now I have a code that makes sure that no class will be applied when the string `special` exists (first form), but I'm not sure how to make it apply the deafult `boo` class for all other cases (Such as second form):

```
<?php
$case1 = "special"; 
$case2 = "not"; 
$a = "aaa"; 
$item = "something"; 

function get_classb( $slug ) {
    $class_map = array(
        'special' => '',
        'default'    => 'boo' // need to change this line
    );

    return ( isset( $class_map[ $slug ] ) ) ? $class_map[ $slug ] : '';
}
?>
<HTML>
<body>
<form action="/go/<?= $item ?>/<?php echo $case1 ; ?>" method="POST" target="_blank">
<input name="a" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $a; ?>"/>
<input type="submit" class="<?php echo get_classb( $case1 ); ?> general-class" value="Click Me"></form>

<form action="/go/<?= $item ?>/<?php echo $case2 ; ?>" method="POST" target="_blank">
<input name="a" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $a; ?>"/>
<input type="submit" class="<?php echo get_classb( $case2 ); ?> general-class" value="Click Me"></form>

</body>
</HTML>
```

Wasn't sure what title to give this question.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, would you not just change

```
return ( isset( $class_map[ $slug ] ) ) ? $class_map[ $slug ] : '';
```

to

```
return ( isset( $class_map[ $slug ] ) ) ? $class_map[ $slug ] : $class_map[ 'default' ];
```

Comment: No problem. If you're happy with the answer, you can mark my answer as accepted (just realised there's a time limit I think, oops!)